# D3JS Javascript and nested functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the link below, I am trying to figure out the meaning of the code.
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/10343037

Here is the particular code I do not understand, it looks like nested functions making a loop working.
I wonder what is the variable `t`, by checking it in the console it is between 0 and 1 but I cannot find where it comes from.
I also do not get the meaning of `.each("end", loop);`

```
!function loop() {
circle.transition()
      .ease("linear")
      .duration(5000)
      .tween("transform", function() {
        return function(t) {
          circle.attr("cx", x(t)).attr("cy", y(ease(t)));
          timeReference.attr("x1", x(t)).attr("x2", x(t)).attr("y2", y(ease(t)));
          easeReference.attr("x2", x(t)).attr("y1", y(ease(t))).attr("y2", y(ease(t)));
        };
      })
      .each("end", loop);
}();
```

Comment: Before asking you are supposed to do at least a little research on your own. Are you aware that there is a detailed [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/API-Reference) covering all parts of D3? The section about [`transition.tween()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#tween) contains all the answers to your first question about `t`. Similarly, the section on [`transition.each()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#each) will answer your second question.

Comment: Thank you for the links, at first I did not know the answers were in the d3 documentation. More than D3.js, I thought that it was Javascript related, that is why I asked here.

Answer (score 1):

you can read more about tween from here to get clear idea of returning function for each selected element.

[Tween function API](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_tween)

Answer (score 0):

According to the following link, the variable `t` is the nomalized time between 0 and 1.

https://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/

Concerning the last statement `.each("end", loop);`, it makes an infinite loop so the animation will restart each time.